# Proof of errors being serially uncorrelated in an AR(1)?

Tags: autocorrelation, autoregressive, conditional-expectation

I am preparing for an econometrics exam and I have reached a lecture on serial correlation which I do not seem to understand the proof. The text I am about to cite is in Wooldridge 6th edition "*Introductory Econometrics*".

It goes like this ...

He presented the following AR(1) model: $$y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1y_{t-1}+u_t$$ $$where \ E[u_t|y_{t-1},y_{t-2}...]=0 \ [1]$$
and he says that for the above AR(1) it holds that $E(u_tu_s|x_tx_s)=0 \ \forall \ t\neq s$

**Question 1**: How do I read $E(u_tu_s|...)=0$?

So the derivation aims to show that $E(u_tu_s|y_{t-1},y_{s-1})=0$. We assume that $s<t$ and we know that $u_s=y_s-\beta_0-\beta_1y_{s-1}$ which shows that $u_s$ is a function of $y$ dated before t.

Then by [1] $\Rightarrow$ $$E(u_t|u_s,y_{t-1},y_{s-1})=0$$

**Question 2**: Why is $u_s$ included above?

and so $$E(u_tu_s|u_s,y_{t-1},y_{s-1})=u_sE(u_t|y_{t-1},y_{s-1})=0$$

**Question 3**: Why do we take $u_s$ into $E(u_tu_s|...)$ and why do we take it out in front?

Then by the "Law of iterated expectations" $$E(u_tu_s|y_{t-1},y_{s-1})\ [2]$$
**Question 4:** How is the law of iterated expectations proves [2]?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There was a "Hello" at the beginning but it does not show :D

Comment: What do you mean by question 1?